# Set "this" in a class

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, view

**EDITED POST**
I'm trying to do kind of MVC for android but lot of tutorials use the `Activity` as the *View*. I would use the `Activity` as the *Controller*.

To do so, I have to create my own classes who extends the `View` class. The easy part is when the *Controller* is an `Activity` because I can do something like this :

```
public class MyView extends View
{
    public MyView(Activity activity)
    {
        activity.setContentView(R.layout.my_view);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is when the *Controller* is a `Fragment` because I cannot use the `setContentView()` method. For fragments, you have to inflate the `View` in the `onCreateView()` method. Right now, I implement this method like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyView myView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        myView = MyView.load(container.getContext);
        return myView;
    }
}
```

And the `MyView` class look like this:

```
public class MyView extends FrameLayout {
    static public MyView load(Context context)
    {
        return (MyView) inflate(context, R.layout.my_fragment, new MyView(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

(It extends `FrameLayout` because the `inflate()` method use a `ViewGroup` as a parameter and `FrameLayout` extends `ViewGroup` and it's easy to use.)

Now, my questions are:
Do you have a better idea to set the content of a fragment ? It is possible to set the content of a fragment in the constructor of the `MyView` class without using the `addView()` method ?

**ORIGNIAL POST**
Instead of explaining my problem, here what I'd like to do :

```
public class MyView extends View
{
    public MyView(View v) {
        this = v;
    }
}
```

But, unfortunately, this is unauthorized because you can't set the "this" keyword.
So, now, I'm doing something like that :

```
public class MyView extends FrameLayout
{
    public MyView(Context context, View v)
    {
        super(context);
        addView(v);
    }
}
```

And it works, but I don't really like this solution because you have to set the ID and everything that come from the view "v" to this new view (for exemple `this.setId(v.getId);` etc) ...

Do you have a better idea to do what I would like to do ?

Comment: Explaining your problem would be better please, it is difficult to understand

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Sure it is, give me a second OP, I'm writing my answer

Comment: "Do you have a better idea to do what I would like to do ?" You haven't really explained what you are trying to achieve, only the approach you've taken so far. Take a step back and describe the original reason you started looking at this.

Comment: You should complete some introductory OOP and Java tutorials.  If you don't understand why you can't assign `this`, you are not ready to build apps.

Comment: I would do something like `this = para;` but I know I can't. So I'm looking for others solutions. I've edited my post. Hope it's more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a method that would do all that for you.

I don't know all the properties of the View class, but let's say your properties are ID, Name, and Number, each having their own getters and setters...

```
public void transferInfo(View v)
{

    this.setID(v.getID());
    this.setName(v.getName());
    this.setNum(v.getNum());

}
```

This way, you can edit all the features of your view, without losing any info. Now, this is an extremely general example, make sure you edit it so that all the features of the original are brought in.

Comment: You mean "properties", not "instances"; the meaning is clear enough from context, but since "instance" means something very specific in OOP, you might want to avoid misusing it.

Comment: The problem here is that you have to know exactly which properties you want to keep. I just want to set the `View v` as the root view of `MyView` class.